# Adding comments to MEAN.JS articles

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, meanjs

I am new to MEAN stack, I am using [MEAN.JS](http://meanjs.org/), which setup my authentication, account management and a CRUD Module for articles, how do i add comments to these articles? Having a tough time to get this. Thanks for the help

Comment: how do you add comments to *what* articles? is `articles` a class on your server (node), or on your client(angular)? is it just an object in the Mongodb? is it something else?  MEAN.JS is just a scaffolding.  Provide some code to show what you are actually trying to do with it.

Comment: MEAN JS uses Yo Generator, giving this command `$ yo meanjs:crud-module <module-name>` creates a CRUD Module, the module-name i gave is "articles".

Comment: ok, so you created an articles class.  what does that have to do with comments? or were you wanting a step by step tutorial in developing your application?

Comment: i am just expecting a method or any process to follow for MEAN.JS, like i said, i am new to this, would really appreciate a link or so to follow

Comment: right, so you ***are*** asking for a tutorial.  That isn't an appropriate question for this site.  You should instead post code showing what you have tried and what specific code is not working.  There are plenty of articles on many sites dedicated to "how-to", this site is dedicated to helping fix broken code.  see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question.

Answer (score 4):

In order to add comments to your MEAN.js Article example you need to do the following steps:

1. In the file `app/models/article.server.model.js` add:

   `comment: {
       type: String,
       default: '',
       trim: true
   },`
2. In the file `public/modules/articles/views/create-article.html` add:

   `<div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label" for="comment">Comment</label>
       <div class="controls">
           <textarea name="comment" data-ng-model="comment" id="comment" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
       </div>
   </div>`
3. In the file `public/modules/articles/controllers/articles.client.controller.js` adjust the `create` function to be:

   `var article = new Articles({
       title: this.title,
       content: this.content,
       comment: this.comment
   });`
4. In the file `public/modules/articles/views/view-article.client.view.html` add this just before the closing `section` tag:

   `<p data-ng-bind="article.comment"></p>`

This is it, now you have a new field `comment` for each article. What you should do now, and I hope it's clear form these instructions here, is alter the editing part of the articles.

Hope this helps, good luck with MEAN.js. And, since you mentioned a tutorial, you're free to take a look [this tutorial series](https://hackhands.com/how-to-get-started-on-the-mean-stack/).

Comment: Could you explain how you could add the ability for users to comment on an article and have every article have its own unique comments? So far i have created a comments module and added the create comment box under each article but how to you create a relationship with the article?

Comment: You can do it with so-called document references (if you have, if I understood correctly, made a new Comments model) about which you can read more from official docs http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/ or from tutorials covering this topic.

Comment: I think i have the Article Model wrong now. Thanks.